# Regex negative lookahead excluding full block

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to put together a regex that would extract me the surface from the below strings, excluding the values that are preceded with Japanese characters.

```
"110.94m2・129.24m2"; --> 110.94m2 and 129.24m2
"81.95m2（24.78坪）、うち2階車庫8.9m2" --> 81.95m2
"80.93m2（登記）" --> 80.93m2
"93.42m2・93.85m2（登記）" --> 93.42m2 and 93.85m2
"81.82m2（実測）" --> 81.82m2
"81.82m2（実測）、うち１階車庫7.82m2" --> 81.82m2
"90.11m2（実測）、うち１階車庫8.07m2" --> 90.11m2
```

So far I have put together the following regex, however not working in every case.

```
(?<![\u4E00-\u9FAF\u3040-\u3096\u30A1-\u30FA\uFF66-\uFF9D\u31F0-\u31FF])([0-9\.]*m2)
```

ie. the following string yields: 81.95m2 and .9m2. I would need only 81.85m2.

```
"81.95m2（24.78坪）、うち2階車庫8.9m2"
```

Would you know how to treat the following block of the negative look ahead as an exclusion?

Thank you

Comment: You have to add `\d.` into your exclusion class: `(?<![\u4E00-\u9FAF\u3040-\u3096\u30A1-\u30FA\uFF66-\uFF9D\u31F0-\u31FF\d.])([0-9\.]*m2)` (or `0-9\.`, if your dialect is forcing you to do that :P )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cancel any match if preceded with a digit or digit + period.

Add `(?<!\d)(?<!\d\.)` after or before the first lookbehind:

```
(?<![\u4E00-\u9FAF\u3040-\u3096\u30A1-\u30FA\uFF66-\uFF9D\u31F0-\u31FF])(?<!\d)(?<!\d\.)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?m2)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9EvkY6/1)

The `(?<!\d)` is a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a digit immediately to the left of the current location and `(?<!\d\.)` fails when there is a digit and a dot right before.

The `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` is a more precise pattern to match numbers like `30` or `30.5678`: 1 or more digits followed with an optional sequence of `.` and 1+ digits.

**NOTE** that this regex will only work with the ES2018+ JS environments (Chrome, Node). You may capture an optional Japanese char into Group 1 and the number into Group 2, then check if Group 1 matched and if yes, fail the match, else, grab Group 2.

The regex is

```
/([\u4E00-\u9FAF\u3040-\u3096\u30A1-\u30FA\uFF66-\uFF9D\u31F0-\u31FF])?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?m2)/g
```

See usage example below.

JS ES2018+ demo:

```js
const lst = ["110.94m2・129.24m2", "81.95m2（24.78坪）、うち2階車庫8.9m2", "80.93m2（登記）", "93.42m2・93.85m2（登記）", "81.82m2（実測）" , "81.82m2（実測）、うち１階車庫7.82m2", "90.11m2（実測）、うち１階車庫8.07m2"];
const regex = /(?<![\u4E00-\u9FAF\u3040-\u3096\u30A1-\u30FA\uFF66-\uFF9D\u31F0-\u31FF])(?<!\d)(?<!\d\.)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?m2)/g;
lst.forEach( s => 
  console.log( s, '=>', s.match(regex) )
);
console.log("Another approach:");
lst.forEach( s => 
  console.log(s, '=>', s.match(/(?<![\p{L}\d]|\d\.)\d+(?:\.\d+)?m2/gu))
)
```

JS legacy ES versions:

```js
var lst = ["110.94m2・129.24m2", "81.95m2（24.78坪）、うち2階車庫8.9m2", "80.93m2（登記）", "93.42m2・93.85m2（登記）", "81.82m2（実測）" , "81.82m2（実測）、うち１階車庫7.82m2", "90.11m2（実測）、うち１階車庫8.07m2"];
var regex = /([\u4E00-\u9FAF\u3040-\u3096\u30A1-\u30FA\uFF66-\uFF9D\u31F0-\u31FF])?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?m2)/g;
for (var i=0; i<lst.length; i++) {
  var m, res =[];
  while (m = regex.exec(lst[i])) {
    if (m[1] === undefined) {
      res.push(m[2]);
    }
  }
  console.log( lst[i], '=>', res );
}
```

**Variations**

If you plan to match a float/int number with `m2` after it that is only preceded with whitespace or at the start of the string use

```
(?<!\S)\d+(?:\.\d+)?m2
```

If you plan to match it when not preceded with any letter use

- [pcre](/questions/tagged/pcre) [java](/questions/tagged/java) - `(?<![\p{L}\d]|\d\.)\d+(?:\.\d+)?m2` (also works in JS ES2018+ environments: `/(?<![\p{L}\d]|\d\.)\d+(?:\.\d+)?m2/gu`)
- [python](/questions/tagged/python) - `(?<!\d\.)(?<![^\W_])\d+(?:\.\d+)?m2`

Note you may add `\b` word boundary after `2` to make sure there is a non-word char after it or end of string.

Comment: @Goul Glad it worked for you. Please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Actually sorry, realize it worked perfectly on the online tester I was using, but not in code. I am using javascript and seems your example is for python?

Comment: Just found the code generator in the site you shared, works well, thanks!

Comment: @Goul I added JS snippets for all browsers.